# Ember Simple Auth 1.0 in Acceptance Tests

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to upgrade an Ember CLI app to use Simple Auth 1.0. My acceptance tests no longer work. I have configured the test suite to run against a Rails server which is a copy of my API. To log in I was doing this:

```
visit("/")
fillIn(".identification-field", "test@email.com");
fillIn(".password-field", "testpassword");
click(".btn.login-submit");

andThen(function(){
  equal(currentSession(application).get('user_email'), "test@email.com");
});
```

This worked with simple-auth 0.7.3 but not with 1.0.0. I have added additional methods my application route to setup the session as follows:

```
_populateCurrentUser: function() {
  var user_id = this.get('session.data.user_id');
  var user_email = this.get('session.data.user_email');
  var _this = this;
  return this.store.find('user', user_id).then(function(user){
     _this.get('currentUser').set('content', user);

     // Below is for backward-compatibility
     _this.get('session').set('currentUser', user);
     _this.get('session').set('user_id', user_id);
     _this.get('session').set('user_email', user_email);
     user;
  });
}

sessionAuthenticated: function(){
  this._populateCurrentUser();
  this._super();
}

beforeModel: function() {
  if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
    return this._populateCurrentUser();
  }
}
```

This is based on the following guide: http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2015/06/18/how-to-inject-the-current-user-using-ember-simple-auth/

This works perfectly when I run the app but breaks my test suite. Now when I log in the session does not seem to be populated - The _populateCurrentUser method fails because this.get('session.data.user_id') is undefined.

Can anyone help with this? Perhaps it is due to the automatic use of the ephemeral session store in 1.0 but if so I am not sure how to get around this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ember Simple Auth 1.0 the session data that the authenticator resolves with is stored in `data.authenticated` so you'd need to change `var user_id = this.get('session.data.user_id');` to `var user_id = this.get('session.data.authenticated.user_id');` etc.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I must have missed this in the docs, thanks for the quick reply